# Analyticity of $\tan(z)$ and radius of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Define $\tan(z)=\dfrac{\sin(z)}{\cos(z)}$

Where is this function defined and analytic?

My answer:

Our function is analytic wherever it has a convergent power series. Since (I am assuming) $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ are analytic the quotient is analytic wherever $\cos(z) \not\to 0$???

Is there more detail to this that I am missing? Without Cauchy is there a way to determine analyticity etc...

Further more, once we have found the first few terms as I have

$$z+\frac{z}{3}+\frac{2}{15}z^5$$

How do we make an estimate of the radius of convergence? Do I make an observation that the terms are getting close to $0$ and say perhaps the $nth$ root is heading there as well, $\therefore$ $R=\infty$. I'm fairly lost on this part.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

The formulation of your question reveals a bit of confusion concerning the issue of analyticity. A function can be analytic beyond its radius of convergence; of course it is not defined there by its power series by rather by *analytic continuation*. The tangent is a good example of this.  The radius of convergence is the distance to the nearest zero of cosine, namely $\pi/2$, but the function is analytic everywhere except for points where cosine vanishes.

Comment: I'm early on in my course so our definition of analytic is wherever it has a convergent power series or wherever it is differentiable on some open ball I believe.,

Comment: In the definition of analyticity, you must specify the point: $f(z)$ is analytic at $z=a$ if the power series **centered on $z=a$** converges in a positive radius around $a$. So although the power series of $\tan(z)$ **centered on $z=0$** will not converge for $|z| > \pi/2$, you will nonetheless find that its power series centered on any point $z=a$ such that $\cos(a) \ne 0$ has a positive radius of converence. @az89

Comment: @LeeMosher, you should mention that your comment is addressed to az89 otherwise he won't be notified.

Comment: I will add that, however, is it not true that the asker of the question is notified of all comments in all answers?

Comment: @LeeMosher, in my experience he is notified of comments *to his question* and answers *to his question*.  Comments to answers to his question violate transitivity :-)

Comment: Comments under an answer auto-notify both the author of the question and the author of the answer.  Also if only two users have posted in the comments under a question or an answer, I think that each will be auto-notified of the other's comments.  Beyond those cases one needs an @ sign to notify a commenter. @LeeMosher

Comment: Hi @zyx and thanks for your comment. This is perhaps how this is *supposed* to work but in practice it doesn't.  Most recently Kutateladze left a *comment* under Dorais' *answer* to my *question* but I didn't get any notification for the comment. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/232584/looking-for-a-source-for-intended-interpretation

Comment: Mathoverflow migrated to the Stackexchange 2.0 platform but not everything is necessarily the same there.   Though the locking(!!) of the MO question shows an unfortunate "convergence" of the two sites.  A few close-voting hardliners shutting down anything that looks slightly out of the ordinary.  You know the routine.

Comment: @zyx, I agree with your analysis and I left some comments under Francois's *answer* there both for him and for Todd. Note that I don't consider either of them a "hardliner" (the latter seem to be doing their work behind the scenes).

Comment: @LeeMosher, a correction to previous comment: I just learned from a moderator's comment that automatic notice to the OP is now only from comments under the question, and comments under answers where OP left a comment.  This would explain user72694's observation.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to check where the function is differentiable, and it is in all of its domain, because
$$
\tan'z=\frac{1}{\cos^2z}
$$

The formal rules for differentiation continue to hold for complex functions.

Comment: I do not follow.

Comment: @az89 What, precisely, is the problem? You said in a comment to the other answer that you know differentiability is sufficient (and also necessary) for the function being analytic.

Answer (score 0):

The Laurent series of $\tan z$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$ is complicated:

$\displaystyle \tan z=z+\frac{z^{3}}{3}+\frac{2}{15}z^{5}+\ldots +
(-1)^{n-1}\frac{2^{2n}(2^{2n}-1)B_{2n}}{(2n)!}z^{2n-1}+\ldots \:, \: |z|<\frac{\pi}{2}$

where $B_{n}$ is Bernoulli number.  The radius of convergence can be justified by $$4\sqrt{n\pi} \left( \frac{n}{\pi e} \right)^{2n} < (-1)^{n-1} B_{2n} <5\sqrt{n\pi} \left( \frac{n}{\pi e} \right)^{2n}$$ for $n\geq 2$.